# Not able to autowire the entity Bean in the project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am new to Spring and Hibernate. I have googled it about this and searched stackoverflow but still I am still not able to solve this problem. So what additional configuration do I need to achieve this functionality.

Here's my code:

### GenerateUserController

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.lejhro.loe.model.GenerateUserModel;
import com.lejhro.loe.service.GenerateUserService;

@Controller
public class GenerateUserController {

    @Autowired
    GenerateUserService generateUserService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sendLoginDetail", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView generate(GenerateUserModel model) {
        return new ModelAndView("sendLoginDetail", "command",
                new GenerateUserModel());
    }

    @RequestMapping("/generateUser")
    public String listGeneratedIds(Model model){
        int totalIds=generateUserService.getTotalIds();
        model.addAttribute("totalIds",totalIds );
        return "/generateUser";
    }
    }
```

### LoginGenerationEntity

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Configurable;

@Configurable
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOGIN_GENERATION")
public class LoginGenerationEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "LOGIN_ID")
    private String loginId;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    @Column(name="EMAIL_ID")
    private String emailId;

    @Column(name = "USED")
    private boolean used = false;


    public String getEmailId() {
        return emailId;
    }

    public void setEmailId(String emailId) {
        this.emailId = emailId;
    }

    public boolean isUsed() {
        return used;
    }

    public void setUsed(boolean used) {
        this.used = used;
    }

    public String getLoginId() {
        return loginId;
    }

    public void setLoginId(String loginId) {
        this.loginId = loginId;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

### GeneratedUserServiceImpl

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.lejhro.loe.dao.GenerateUserDao;
import com.lejhro.loe.entity.LoginGenerationEntity;
import com.lejhro.loe.service.GenerateUserService;
import com.lejhro.loe.utils.Utility;

@Service
public class GeneratedUserServiceImpl implements GenerateUserService{

        @Autowired
        LoginGenerationEntity loginGenerationEntity;
//LoginGenerationEntity loginGenerationEntity= new LoginGenerationEntity();//this works

    @Autowired
    GenerateUserDao generateUserDao;

    @Transactional
    public void saveGeneratedInfo() {

        String userId=null;
        String password = null;
        userId=Utility.getRandomNumber(10);
        password= Utility.getRandomNumber(10);
        loginGenerationEntity.setLoginId(userId);
        loginGenerationEntity.setPassword(password);
        generateUserDao.save(loginGenerationEntity);
    }
```

I have added these two in `Spring-servlet.xml`

```
<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="autodetect" />
    <context:spring-configured/>
```

I have added these lines in the `pom.xml`. I am not showing the other dependencies.

```
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-javaagent:${user.home}/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-agent/${spring.version}/spring-agent-${spring.version}.jar</argLine>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-agent</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring.version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

### StackTrace

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.weaving.AspectJWeavingEnabler#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1079)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:643)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:407)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loadTimeWeaver': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.weaving.LoadTimeWeaverAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(LoadTimeWeaverAwareProcessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar
    at org.springframework.context.weaving.DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.setBeanClassLoader(DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.java:83)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1436)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 35 more

Dec 30, 2013 11:41:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /LOE threw load() exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ClassLoader [org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader] does NOT provide an 'addTransformer(ClassFileTransformer)' method. Specify a custom LoadTimeWeaver or start your Java virtual machine with Spring's agent: -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument.jar
    at org.springframework.context.weaving.DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.setBeanClassLoader(DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver.java:83)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1436)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1408)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.weaving.LoadTimeWeaverAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(LoadTimeWeaverAwareProcessor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1079)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:643)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:407)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:442)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:339)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: You probably don't need load time weaving, remove this: `<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="autodetect" />`

Comment: @RC Ok, I have removed it but still the same... Is there any problem with the lines that i have added in the pom.xml ?

Comment: I doubt it's "the same", please provide the stacktrace of the error you get without `<context:load-time-weaver` also I don't think you need the agent config for surefire

Comment: @RC i have added the stacktrace in answer without <context:load-time-weaver

Comment: Does the LoginGenerationEntity bean have the right scope? It looks to me like the sort of bean that ought to have `prototype` scope, yet I think it's probably `singleton` by default. (I don't know how the Hibernate annotations interact with this, but it's where I'd look for trouble to begin.)

Answer (score 1):

Create instance for the entity bean instead of autowiring it, like this:

```
@Transactional
public void saveGeneratedInfo() {
    final LoginGenerationEntity loginGenerationEntity = new LoginGenerationEntity();
    loginGenerationEntity.setLoginId(Utility.getRandomNumber(10));
    loginGenerationEntity.setPassword(Utility.getRandomNumber(10));

    generateUserDao.save(loginGenerationEntity);
}
```

Comment: I have mentioned it is working without autowiring it, but i want to achieve it with autowiring.

Comment: It's mandatory to create a new instance user3016905 is right. I added a correct `saveGeneratedInfo()` to his/her answer

Comment: @RC yaa without autowiring and creating new instance of Entity it is working well previously. So is it better to create new instance instead of autowiring the Entity ?

Comment: Yes it is..
Entity makes a table.. So it is not a good idea to autowire a table.. better avoid autowiring entity.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding

```
<context:component-scan />
```

in spring xml

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why would you want your entity to be a member variable and dependency injected into your Processor? Is this what you want? You should probably have a DAO which is used to get/update/create to the DB. Shouldnt you be passing values into your processor, from your controller, then wrapping them into an Entity and create/updating them?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component//First change here...
@Configurable
@Entity
@Table(name = "LOGIN_GENERATION")
public class LoginGenerationEntity {
.....
}

@Service//Second change here...
public class GenerateUserDao {
....
}

Use "@Component" annotaion in the LoginGenerationEntity
than try to use.

        @Autowired
        LoginGenerationEntity loginGenerationEntity;


Reference from Spring documentation:
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-stereotype-annotations 
Chapter - 4.10.4 Defining bean metadata within components
```